# Creating a pine script strategy that goes long if yesterday was bullish

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a simple strategy where a green candle would result in a buy the next day. The script is super simple:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Yesterday Cat", overlay=true)
if time>timestamp(2018, 01, 01, 0, 0)
    bullish = open[1] < open
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1, when=bullish)
    strategy.close("buy", not bullish)
```

The resulting graph is way wonky though:

[image: Graph]

I would expect candle 2 being the reason for a buy on the opening of candle 3, and then candle 6 resulting in a sale when candle 7 opens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply - but if you're still interested this does what you're after:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Yesterday Cat", overlay=true)
if time > timestamp(2018, 01, 01, 0, 0)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1, when = close > open)
    strategy.close("buy", when = close < open)
```

FYI looking at the previous open (e.g. open[1]) was delaying the entry by a bar as strategies make an entry on the open of a bar. It had to wait an additional bar to meet the conditions. Using close > open fixes that.

Works relatively well on heiken ashi charts as you stay in trends longer.